# Can you use images from a data stick in an android app?

Tags: android, forms

I am designing and implementing an android application which is basically a survey with the capability to insert images and audio files.

What I am wondering is, is it possible for the android app to insert images directly from a USB data stick into a form?

Furthermore any pointers on how to do this, or to resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes. That is of course possible. Why do you think it wouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

Android 3.1 or later devices (API level 12 or later), or Android 2.3.4 (API 10) with the compatibility library, support reading from USB sticks IF the hardware supports it (i.e. if the manufacturer added the support), which usually means recent devices that support OTG (On-The-Go), usually via an OTG adapter. Apps need "android.hardware.usb.host" uses feature in manifest and must handle USB_PERMISSION.

Start with the developer info: [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)

which doesn't give detail on the code to actually access files. [libMedia](http://libeasy.alwaysdata.net/) is a commercial library that has a class to access sticks. If you can see the USB drive in a file explorer App you may be able to access it with file IO code using directory names such as /mnt/sda1/, /mnt/sda/sda1/, /udisk/, /mnt/udisk/. The file explorer should show the path.